# How to handle generated columns in the declarative model when inserting data into a postgres table?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

If the table in postgres is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    email text UNIQUE,
    height_cm numeric,
    height_in numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS (height_cm / 2.54) STORED
);
```

And the sqlalchemy model is:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class User(declarative_base()):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    height_cm = Column(Numeric)
    height_in = Column(Numeric)
```

How to correctly deal with the generated `height_in` column is sqlalchemy?

The idea is to only insert `id`, `email` and `height_cm` using sqlalchemy however by specifying the column `height_in` sqlalchemy automatically inserts NULL into `height_in` when inserting a row into the table - and postgres then errors out as this is not allowed.

Comment: Note: the `GENERATED ALWAYS AS ... STORED` syntax seems to have been introduced in Postgresql v12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare the column as [Computed](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html?highlight=computed#sqlalchemy.schema.Computed):

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    height_cm = Column(Numeric)
    height_in = Column(Numeric, Computed("height_cm / 2.54"))

    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            f"<User(id={self.id}, email='{self.email}', "
            f"height_cm={self.height_cm}, height_in={self.height_in})>"
        )


Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
"""DDL generated:
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    height_cm NUMERIC, 
    height_in NUMERIC GENERATED ALWAYS AS (height_cm / 2.54) STORED, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
"""

with Session(engine) as session:
    foo = User(email="foo@bar.baz", height_cm=175)
    session.add(foo)
    session.commit()
    print(foo)
    # <User(id=1, email='foo@bar.baz', height_cm=175, height_in=68.8976377952755906)>
```